# How to change text's fore color of Menu Strip in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

The default color is black and I can't find the relevant property to change the fore color. Can you advise please?

Comment: ForeColor property is found at every item's properties chart. Not at the main MenuStrip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ForeColor can be change but I think you will have to do this at runtime:

```
ToolStripMenuItem1.ForeColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond
```